# How should multiple anticipated degrees be listed on the CV?

Tags: cv

I'm in the process of completing a PhD and will be concurrently awarded an MS in a different field when I graduate (i.e., PhD in A, MS in B). While there is a fairly fixed format for the PhD listing (e.g., "In Progress" or "Defending YYYY") to provide relevant information for search committees, how should other degrees in progress be listed?

Comment: One specific note to my situation, the MS is in a completely different field so it is actually quite useful in the job hunt since it opens additional opportunities.

Comment: Clearly. They should be listed clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

*Ph.D. Theoretical Junk, Enormous State University, 2019 (defending June)

*M.S. Useful Shiznat, Enormous State University, 2019 (May completion)